# How can I style the overflow menu?

Tags: android

I tried adding this style to my main Theme:

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.PopupMenu</item>
```

but the background appears clear, and when I press a row, it turns white.

I'm trying to style the overflow menu like the Holo dark theme.

Comment: What theme does your app's current theme extend from?

Comment: So I get a light actionBar, a Dark popup menu when I click the overflow icon (which doesn't play nicely with the dark text color for the menu items), and pressing an item gives me the standard holo blue highlight. Does your app use white to highlight anything else? (list items, selectableItemBackground, etc)

Comment: Yes.    --------------------------

Comment: A lot of the android styles reference other theme attributes. I suggest rummaging through the platform `styles.xml` and `themes.xml` and try to figure out what attributes exactly are involved and how certain styles will be affected by it. You can find those files in `<android-sdk-directory>/platforms/android-##/data/res/values'. You can also look at `attrs.xml` in the same directory. Be aware that not all the styles and attributes you find can be used by you; the ones that are available for public consumption are listed in `public.xml` in the same folder.

Comment: So I'll have to override system style items?

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly tell you how to set what theme/color. But you may use [this link](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to help you generate some custom style/theme for your app. Further, if you reverse-engineer the style resource file, you may figure out how things are defined internally regarding `android:popupMenuStyle`.

Comment: I don't want to create my own style. I want to use the out-of-the-box Holo style that I use throughout my app. Is this possible?

Comment: @Rose Perrrone-I guess you may use Actionbarsherlock library it contains so many theme that u can apply to popup menu,actionbar.Hope this helps you

Comment: Did you try using `<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow</item>`? You can find this hint if you create a standard resource theme, extract the file and locate **popupMenyStyle**.

Comment: That still makes a dark background with black text and it turns white when I select it, but I can ovirride those attributes.

Comment: perhaps try with light theme, for e.g. `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow`